# remove objects from last row of dynamic datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a winform datagridview:

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Check", typeof(bool));
        table.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(Image));


        using (RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\xyz"))
        {

            foreach (string keyname in root.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey key = root.OpenSubKey(keyname))
                {
                    if (keyname == sentKeyName)
                    {
                        foreach (string valuename in key.GetValueNames())
                        {
                            if (key.GetValue(valuename) is String)
                            {
                                Image image = Image.FromFile(@"Image1.jpg");

                                table.Rows.Add(false, valuename, key.GetValue(valuename), image);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                             
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

now i put an image and checkbox in the table as shown above.

it works fine when i have values, but for the last  row which is blank and can be edited gets populated by the checkbox and the error image symbol.

Also is there a way to make one column as read only.

any suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that extra row because you are allowing the user to add a new row. If you want to disable adding a new row (and hide the ugly extra row), use the following:

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

To make a single column read only, do the following:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Status"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Make sure to call this AFTER you've set the DataSource.

**Update:**

I'm unable to test anything out at the moment, but the [DataGridViewImageColumn.DefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.defaultcellstyle.aspx) property seems to be what you are looking for, particularly:

> To prevent the error graphic from
>   appearing in the row for new records
>   when the control AllowUserToAddRows
>   property value is true, you must also
>   either explicitly set the cell value
>   to null or your own error graphic in a
>   handler for the control RowsAdded
>   event or set the column CellTemplate
>   property to an instance of a
>   DataGridViewImageCell-derived type
>   with an overridden DefaultNewRowValue
>   property that returns null or your own
>   error graphic.

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply.. but i want the last row so that a user can add values.. i want to hide the image.. if thats possible?.. or ill have to take another approach..